# How generate inside ng-click jquery plugins?

Tags: angularjs, directive, angularjs-ng-click

thisJS:

```
$('#blockID').ajaxUpload({
    url : 'services/uploadImgage.php',
    name: 'file',
    data: { 

    },
    onSubmit: function() {

    },
    onComplete: function(result) {

    }
});
```

Such code I figure to plase inside ng-click function but don't know how. I think to plase this code indide directives but don't know appear in future probles with response data manipulation. How I should done?

Comment: Read this "AngularJS for jQuery developers". It will help you. In short: you should use custom directive.

Comment: this one: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-for-the-jquery-developer.html   ???

Comment: You don't want to use jQuery code in angularjs, you might want to look into `$http`.

Comment: This one will be very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background